# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Horizontal items overlapping on ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We've got an simple collection view for horizontal items. See code below.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="1">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Padding="10">
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Item_Tapped" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image
                                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                           VerticalOptions="Fill"
                                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                                           HeightRequest="60"
                                           WidthRequest="60" />
                                    <Label
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

On android this works great and I've got items stand neatly next to each other. On iOS the items are overlapping each other. Cannot find why this doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: I used your code and it works fine on my side.So you can provide a sample so that I can test it .

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? We've been struggling this off and on for a week and can't seem to find a way to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @NorthFork, no i didn't find an solution. I went back to an horizontal stackpanel cause we we didn't have any time left on the project.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the response. If anyone else sees this we had a bit of a break through. In our code we were showing a panel with a loading indicator during loading, then hiding it and showing the CollectionView after the data had loaded. We did this by binding the IsVisible property of both to a bindable property on the view model. When we removed the IsVisible binding and left it visible full time, the problem went away. Was something about the redraw on making it visible I guess.